# How to get number of digits in an integer with leading zeros in java?

Tags: java, integer, number-formatting, digit, leading-zero

This question includes numbers with leading zeros and numbers which normally counted as hexadecimal(like 09).Assume user input is integer,because i pass number to some function as integer.

**For example**

- if user inputs 5    i should get 1
- if user inputs 0005 i should
  get 4
- if user inputs 09     i should get 2

(Note)Below method does not work:

```
String.valueOf(integer).length()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user input will probably be a `String` already, so you could just use `String.length()`. For example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String number = in.next();
    int numDigits = number.length();
    System.out.println(numDigits);
}
```

If the input were an integer, it couldn't have leading zeros. If the initial input had zeros and you converted it to an integer at some point, you lost this information.

Comment: I've edited my question.Assume input will be as integer.

Comment: If the input were an integer, it couldn't have leading zeros. If the initial input had zeros and you converted it to an integer at some point, you lost this information.

Comment: Yes, the question as written is now malformed. Leading zeroes are only a characteristic of strings.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if the number you want is a String. You don't have 0005 integer numbers unless it is not an integer, it is a String instead.
You have to save those numbers as a String instead of a int for this to work. Then you can use the `.length()` method